# Runtime exceptions when trying to migrate from MySQL to MS SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I have a spring boot application(https://github.com/khandelwal-arpit/springboot-starterkit-mysql)that works fine when I use a MySQL database and configuration. However I want to migrate to MS SQL Server because I can't live update data visuals in Microsoft Power Bi when using MySQL so that's why the change is necessary.

This is the MySQL Configuration in the application.properties file:

```
#Default server port
server.port=8080

### MySQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST:localhost}:${DB_PORT:3306}/${DB_NAME:brs}?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=${MYSQL_USER:root}
spring.datasource.password=${MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD:password}

##Set active profile
spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@

#logging.level.web=${LOG_LEVEL:DEBUG}
#management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

Configuration for MS SQL Server:

```
#Default server port
server.port=8080

# MS SQL Server JDBC properties
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=brs
spring.datasource.username=jay
spring.datasource.password=M@nUnit3dBaCk0nT0p

# Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**Console logged exceptions PS: There's more but it's too long**

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table user (user_id bigint identity not null, email varchar(255), first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255), mobile_number varchar(255), password varchar(255), primary key (user_id))" via JDBC Statement
>
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table agency add constraint FK8y56hykf78k5u3wmutny52wcf foreign key (owner_user_id) references user" via JDBC Statement
>
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table ticket add constraint FKdvt57mcco3ogsosi97odw563o foreign key (user_id) references user" via JDBC Statement
>
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table user_role add constraint FK859n2jvi8ivhui0rl0esws6o foreign key (user_id) references user" via JDBC Statement
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>
> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.

Comment: You apparently can't have a table named `user` in SQL Server. Try naming it `user_tbl`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch you certainly can but because `user` is a reserved word you need to enquote it with square brackets, i.e.: `create table dbo.[User] ( ... )`. It's still named `User` in `sys.objects`, you just need the square brackets when referencing it using T-SQL syntax.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I considered that, and while I know it would work for T-SQL, would it still work for MySQL? Because I wasn't sure I just commented.